# SOQL on OpportunityFieldHistory does not return ALL Stage changes

Tags: soql, stagename

I have a problem with the SOQL and OpportunityFieldHistory object.

When I go to the Opportunity Stage History related list I can see 8 changes on the Opportunity Stage, but when I do the query to OpportunityFieldHistory object to retrieve the stage update, only appears 3 changes.

[image: Stage History related list]
[image: SOQL query on Opportunity]
Can you help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was my mistake, I was querying *OpportunityFieldHistory* instead of *OpportunityHistory*.

Comment: Yep, `OpportunityHistory` is for StageName (and also Amount, Probability, and CloseDate)